# Insert Content into Script with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm putting a map on my site and I'd like certain co-ordinates in the map to be editable from the admin.

```
var geoJson = [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-75.00, 40]
},
```

Putting it as follows breaks it

```
var geoJson = [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [<?php the_field('co_ordinates'); ?>]
},
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this between `<script></script>` tags in a PHP file or in a .js file?